# Mocking with ldap3: TypeError: 'NotImplementedType' object is not callable

Tags: python, mocking, ldap3

I'm trying to run the example for mocking with `ldap3` from [the documentation](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/mocking.html):

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ldap3 import Server, Connection, MOCK_SYNC
>>> server = Server('my_fake_server')
>>> connection = Connection(server, user='cn=my_user,ou=test,o=lab',password='my_password',client_strategy=MOCK_SYNC)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ldap3/core/connection.py", line 270, in __init__
    self.strategy = MockSyncStrategy(self)
TypeError: 'NotImplementedType' object is not callable
```

Does anyone know why this fails?

Comment: Perhaps you are using a old version of ldap3. Which version is this?

Comment: Good point. It's ldap3 version 1.2.2, which is the current version available as a package for Debian 9.6.  However, I see that, Debian being Debian, 1.2.2 is over 2 1/2 years old and the current version of ldap3 is 2.5.1.  After updating to ldap3 2.5.1 via pip the error disappears. Thanks!